# Question about the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbb{Z}_l$-linear map induced by $n$th power of Frobenius morphism

Tags: linear-algebra, elliptic-curves

Let $\phi: E \rightarrow E$ be the Frobenius morphism on an elliptic curve given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x^q, y^q)$ where $q$ is a prime power.

It induces a map on Tate module $T_l(E) = \varprojlim_{n} E[l^n]$, $E[l^n]$ is the set of all points of $E$ of order $l^n$ (here $n \geq 1$.) as below

$$ \phi_l : T_l(E) \rightarrow T_l(E) $$

It is given that $\phi_l$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_l$-linear map with characteristic polynomial say, $(T-\alpha)(T-\beta)$.

Now let $\phi^n : E(\mathbb{F}_{q^n}) \rightarrow E(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})$ be the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x^{q^n}, y^{q^n})$ and it similarly it induces a linear map on corresponding Tate module $\phi_l^n$.

My question: how do I find characteristic polynomial for $\phi_l^n$? The book says to triangularise/find Jordan normal form of it. 
The book says that it will be $(T- \alpha^n)(T-\beta^n)$.

But I'm not sure how to go on about finding this.

I'd be thankful if someone could help me out on this.

Comment: You can always choose a $\overline{\mathbb Q}_l$-basis of $T_l(E)\otimes \overline{\mathbb Q}_l$ such that $\phi_l$ is upper triangular - i.e. so that $\phi_l = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&*\\0&\beta\end{pmatrix}$. In this basis, you can read off what $\phi_l^n$ is. The characteristic polynomial does not depend on the choice of basis, nor does it depend on the extension of scalars.

Comment: Could you explain why we needed to consider a $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_l}$-basis of $T_l(E) \otimes \bar{\mathbb{Q}_l}$? From what I understand, I would want to choose a $\mathbb{Z}_l$-basis of $T_l(E)$ which would give me a $2 \times 2$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_l$.

Comment: You would normally consider $T_l(E)$ as a $\mathbb Z_l$-module, sure. But it may be that there is no $\mathbb Z_l$-basis in which $\phi_l$ is upper triangular. However, there is certainly an $\overline{\mathbb Q}_l$-basis in which it is, and the scalar extension does not changed the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. Thank you!